# SPFX library code is also bundled with webpart code

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have deployed a library and webpart in sharepoint and later I updated the library and deployed it again then I have noticed the code in the previous version library is getting executed.

I have also noticed the library component was not included in the script resources property of webpart manifest which was generated after gulp bundle --ship

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the version to higher one in both config/package-solution.json and package.json.
2. Do gulp build --ship, then gulp bundle --ship then do gulp package-solution --ship.
3. After adding the new version to appcatalog, go to the local site, Site Contents, find the webpart, click on details, then update.
4. Ctrl+F5 on the page where the webpart was deployed.

Comment: I have tried but still facing the same issue. I think the issue is the library component code is also bundle with the webpart code

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Did you try deleting the library?

Comment: no, I have deployed it without deleting the existing package

Comment: I didn't mean package, but library itself. It can't run it over. Only create it.

Comment: I removed the library in the app catalog and deployed it again, but still facing the same issue

Comment: I will make some screenshots when I get the time. It shouldn't be happening but let's see if it will help you.

Comment: @ramagirishkarri were you able to make it work?